# Kafka Consumer not able to consume message of 905 bytes for JsonDeserializer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are using Spring with Kafka consumer & producers. We are producing messages of size 905 bytes. We are serializing message and trying to de-serialize it for next consumer.

**Message Payload Class Sample:**

```
{  
        "FILE_LIST":[  
            {
                "KEY1": "Large String Value",
                "KEY2": "Large String Value",
                "Key3": "Large String Value",
                "Key4": "Large String Value"
            }
        ]
}
```

Payload class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InnerModel {

    @JsonProperty("KEY1")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String key1;

    @JsonProperty("KEY2")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String key2;

    @JsonProperty("KEY3")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String key3;

    @JsonProperty("KEY4")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String key4;
}
```

**CustomModel.java**

```
 package com.consumer.model; 


public class CustomModel {
    public CustomModel(List<InnerModel> filesList) {
        super();
        this.filesList = filesList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("FILE_LIST")
    @NonNull
    @Getter
    @Setter
    List<InnerModel> filesList;
}
```

**Consumer Code**

```
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaHandler;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@KafkaListener(topics = "customtopic", groupId = "customgroup")
public class CustomModelConsumer {
    @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
    private void consumeCustomModel(CustomModel model) {
        System.out.println("Model Consumer");
        System.out.println(model);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.compression-type=gzip 
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=com.consumer.model
```

**Consumer works well when we accept message payload in string format, but we are facing problem when we de-serialize payload in consumer to object.** Below error is thrown for same

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition customtopic-0 at offset 70. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
>   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[123, 34, 73, 78, 80, 85, 84, 95, 70, 73, 76, 69, 95, 76, 73, 83, 84, 34, 58, 91, 123, 34, 79, 82, 73, 71, 73, 78, 65, 76, 95, 67, 76, 73, 80, 95, 67, 85, 82, 82, 69, 78, 84, 34, 58, 34, 115, 51, 58, 47, 47, 98, 45, 97, 111, 45, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 45, 109, 111, 99, 107, 47, 55, 52, 49, 48, 57, 102, 98, 98, 45, 54, 102, 52, 101, 45, 52, 48, 54, 50, 45, 97, 98, 48, 102, 45, 100, 49, 102, 53, 98, 98, 102, 55, 49, 97, 56, 49, 47, 99, 108, 105, 112, 115, 47, 48, 58, 48, 48, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 49, 48, 48, 48, 95, 111, 114, 105, 103, 105, 110, 97, 108, 99, 108, 105, 112, 47, 48, 58, 48, 48, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 48, 58, 48, 48, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 48, 58, 48, 48, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 46, 109, 112, 52, 34, 44, 34, 79, 82, 73, 71, 73, 78, 65, 76, 95, 67, 76, 73, 80, 95, 71, 76, 79, 66, 65, 76, 95, 84, 73, 77, 69, 83, 84, 65, 77, 80, 95, 67, 85, 82, 82, 69, 78, 84, 34, 58, 34, 115, 51, 58, 47, 47, 98, 45, 97, 111, 45, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 45, 109, 111, 99, 107, 47, 55, 52, 49, 48, 57, 102, 98, 98, 45, 54, 102, 52, 101, 45, 52, 48, 54, 50, 45, 97, 98, 48, 102, 45, 100, 49, 102, 53, 98, 98, 102, 55, 49, 97, 56, 49, 47, 99, 108, 105, 112, 115, 47, 48, 58, 48, 48, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 49, 48, 48, 48, 95, 111, 114, 105, 103, 105, 110, 97, 108, 99, 108, 105, 112, 47, 48, 58, 48, 48, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 48, 58, 48, 48, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 95, 116, 115, 47, 48, 58, 48, 48, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 95, 116, 115, 46, 106, 115, 111, 110, 34, 44, 34, 79, 82, 73, 71, 73, 78, 65, 76, 95, 67, 76, 73, 80, 95, 78, 69, 88, 84, 34, 58, 34, 115, 51, 58, 47, 47, 98, 45, 97, 111, 45, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 45, 109, 111, 99, 107, 47, 55, 52, 49, 48, 57, 102, 98, 98, 45, 54, 102, 52, 101, 45, 52, 48, 54, 50, 45, 97, 98, 48, 102, 45, 100, 49, 102, 53, 98, 98, 102, 55, 49, 97, 56, 49, 47, 99, 108, 105, 112, 115, 47, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 54, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 49, 48, 48, 48, 95, 111, 114, 105, 103, 105, 110, 97, 108, 99, 108, 105, 112, 47, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 54, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 54, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 54, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 46, 109, 112, 52, 34, 44, 34, 79, 82, 73, 71, 73, 78, 65, 76, 95, 67, 76, 73, 80, 95, 71, 76, 79, 66, 65, 76, 95, 84, 73, 77, 69, 83, 84, 65, 77, 80, 95, 78, 69, 88, 84, 34, 58, 34, 115, 51, 58, 47, 47, 98, 45, 97, 111, 45, 112, 114, 111, 100, 117, 99, 116, 45, 109, 111, 99, 107, 47, 55, 52, 49, 48, 57, 102, 98, 98, 45, 54, 102, 52, 101, 45, 52, 48, 54, 50, 45, 97, 98, 48, 102, 45, 100, 49, 102, 53, 98, 98, 102, 55, 49, 97, 56, 49, 47, 99, 108, 105, 112, 115, 47, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 54, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 49, 48, 48, 48, 95, 111, 114, 105, 103, 105, 110, 97, 108, 99, 108, 105, 112, 47, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 54, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 47, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 54, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 95, 116, 115, 47, 48, 58, 48, 51, 58, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48, 48, 95, 48, 58, 48, 54, 58, 48, 48, 46, 50, 48, 48, 95, 116, 115, 46, 106, 115, 111, 110, 34, 125, 93, 125]] from topic [customtopic]
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.consumer.model.CustomModel` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
>    at [Source: (byte[])"{"FILE_LIST":[{"KEY1":"Large String Value","KEY2":"Large String Value","Key3":"Large String Value"[truncated 405 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1290) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1611) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1234) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
>       at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:198) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:923) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$2600(Fetcher.java:93) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1100) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1200(Fetcher.java:949) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:570) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:531) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1146) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1103) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:667) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]

Comment: Can you please share the configuration of consumer

Comment: done, have updated it completely

Comment: `com.consumer.model.CustomModel` do not have a default constructor. Hence you are seeing this issue. In the exception stack trace its clearly mentioned. `Cannot construct instance of com.consumer.model.CustomModel (no Creators, like default construct, exist):`

Comment: Thank You, Don't know. How I missed that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Naveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2318227/naveen-kumar), I was missing default or all-args constructor. Changed the code as shown below, to make it work

```
package com.consumer.model; 

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomModel {   
  @JsonProperty("FILE_LIST")
  @NonNull
  @Getter
  @Setter
  List<InnerModel> filesList;
}
```